# Php : Replace filename and variable dynamically in file

Tags: php

I have one folder `/var/www/html/${Entityname}/abc.php`

and in `abc.php` file

```
<?php
/**
 * ${Entityname}
 *
 */

namespace ${Entityname}\${Modulename}\Setup;

class ${Entityname}Setup extends EavSetup
{
    ${Entityname} = 'testing';  
}
```

I want to do like that, If I add value in first textbox then, that value replace at `${Entityname}`. If I add value in second textbox then, that value replace at `${Modulename}` and then add that new file in one folder.

I tried something like that (testing.php):

```
<?php
$lines = file('names.php');
$search = '${Entityname}';

$result = 'Test';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (stripos($line, $search) === false) {
        $result .= $line;
    }
}
file_put_contents('names2.php', $result);
```

**EDIT :**

My Folder Path : `/var/www/html/${Entityname}/abc.php`

I execute file from `/var/www/html/testing.php`

there are two textbox available in testing.php file. Now, which value I add in first textbox, It should be replace on ${Entityname} (in foldername and file code both) and then that new file will be add in new folder.

User added **Stack** in first textbox and **Overflow** in second textbox. So, output should be like this :

> /var/www/html/Stack/abc.php

Means **Stack** folder create and **abc.php** file add in that.

and **abc.php** file should be like :

```
<?php
/**
 * Stack
 *
 */

namespace Stack\Overflow\Setup;

class StackSetup extends EavSetup
{
    Stack = 'testing';  
}
```

How to do it ?

I'm new for that. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to do like this?

Comment: I want to make dynamically file and folder which user set name in textbox.

Comment: Can you show your full requirement so that I can suggest you better way?

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: Why not just read the file with `file_get_contents()` and then use `str_replace()` to replace the values?

Comment: It would be better if you post code as answer :)

Comment: file_get_contents() doesn't read class path, namespace from file.

Comment: That comment makes little sense. Both `file()` and `file_get_contents()` just reads the contents of a file. The difference is that `file()` gives you an array with one element per line while `file_get_contents()` will give you the contents as one string. You still get all the contents.

Comment: Your question also says that the result should be saved as `/var/www/html/Stack/abc.php` while your code is saving it as `names2.php`?

Comment: I edit question also. It's just example code. You can get better idea which I edited.  I exactly want like that.

Comment: @AmitRajput any solution?

Comment: @Ankita show me your testing.php file code.

Comment: Check it updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use mkdir function to create folder for PHP

`<?php
    mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>`